# Como utilizar IValidatableObject?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Como utilizar o `IValidatableObject` para não validar a uma propriedade de chave estrangeira durante um cadastro? Quero validar apenas a chave estrangeira na edição.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) pede para implementar [`Validate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate(v=vs.110).aspx), que é um método que recebe como argumento um [`ValidationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    /* Aqui entra a validação em si */
}
```

Para o seu caso, como você apenas quer validar na edição, isto quer dizer que a chave primária está preenchida. Então a lógica ficaria assim:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (this.EntidadeId != null && this.EntidadeId > 0) {
        if (this.EntidadeEstrangeiraId == null || this.EntidadeEstrangeiraId <= 0) {
            yield return new ValidationResult("É necessário definir um valor de EntidadeEstrangeira", new [] { "EntidadeEstrangeiraId" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal, é semelhante ao FluentValidation, vou utilizar nesse projeto. Valeu demais!!