# Fazer validação por js com for each

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta tela preciso fazer uma validação para que em cada registro, quando o registro tiver permissão, no caso dele estiver marcado me trazer o registro com ele marcado toda vez que editar(marcar ou desmarcar o checkbox).

No caso a melhor forma que achei é usando o `foreach` no javascript e tenho que validar os casos seguindo exemplo abaixo.

Para cada funcionalidade, ou seja (manter material, solicitar material, enviar relatorios e requisitar material) fazer uma validação para cada ação no caso (visualizar tela, pesquisar, cadastrar, editar, ativar/inativar e solicitar estorno) no caso ficando 24 validações. Estou correta?

Queria um exemplo de como poderia fazer isso da melhor forma possivel. 
Já procurei mas não achei algo especifico para resolver o meu problema.
Estou fazendo um projeto em C# em MVC.

Sendo que cada permissao é um identificador diferente e tambem depende de cada perfil escolhido.

Comment: Você está usando GridView?

Comment: Por favor, coloquei seu código da *View* na pergunta.

Comment: Isso. Correto. Com a tag table normal dai.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Onde?

Comment: Basta [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código usado para gerar a *View*.

Comment: Você precisa de todos os registros onde o checkbox, quando alterado, for checked ? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez me desculpe mas não encontrei o codigo...

Comment: Essa tela que está no corpo da pergunta, não tem código algum começado, é isso?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Teria como especificar melhor onde encontro, ou mandar como comentário mesmo, porque pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não tem nenhum codigo começado para validar isso não. Só a função que ao selecionar um perfil ele carrega a gridview... somente isto

Comment: @devgaspa Sim exatamente. Preciso que quando o checkbox for alterado pra checked ou nao checked quero que ele atualize meu banco, no caso sao dados booleanos.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, como não tem código começado, vou sugerir um.

Validações normalmente são anotadas em *Model*. Podem ser por atributos ou implementando [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx). Um exemplo de validação por atributos seria:

```
public class Perfil
{
    [Key]
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }

    [Required] // Required é um atributo que obriga o usuário
               // a preencher o campo em tela.
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

[Aqui tem mais exemplos de validação por atributos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation).

Já `IValidatableObject` te obriga a implementar um método chamado `Validate`:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Coloque aqui sua lógica para validação.
        // Cada problema de validação deve devolver um objeto do tipo
        // ValidationResult.
    }
```

[Aqui explico melhor como usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94776/como-utilizar-ivalidatableobject/94782#94782).

Feito isso, na *View* basta adicionar a referência ao [jQuery Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validation) que sua `GridView` já está pronta para usar validação.