# Qual a forma mais "limpa" e clara de validar entidades utilizando o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataannotations, fluent-api

Estou utilizando o Entity Framework para manipulação de dados. O projeto está dividido em 2, um contendo as **entidades de domínio** e a outra os mapeamentos (**Fluent Api**). Preciso de uma forma "limpa" e clara de validar as entidades sem poluir as entidades com DataAnnotations, sabendo que estou a utilizar o Fluent Api para configurá-las. Devo utilizar o DataAnnotations? Qual a melhor forma de validá-las?

Comment: Depende, cara... Se sua aplicação tem interface pra usuário, é melhor tu criar View Models e aplicar DataAnnotation nela... No domínio você aplica a regra de negócio e pra não arriscar, validação da integridade dos dados.

Comment: Atributos de DataAnnotation têm pouca utilidade em *ViewModels*, como `ScaffoldColumn` e `ScaffoldTable`, que são modificadores de banco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Preciso de uma forma "limpa" e clara de validar as entidades sem poluir as entidades com DataAnnotations, sabendo que estou a utilizar o Fluent Api para configurá-las.

O que você quer dizer com "poluir as entidades"?

A melhor forma de trabalhar com validação é pela decoração por atributos ([pertencentes ao *namespace* `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)). Com ela, o *Model* se torna uma representação completa de um registro em banco de dados, com suporte a validação e descrição de relacionamento com outras entidades.

Não há problema em utilizar a *Fluent API* para decorar os elementos de dados de cada entidade, mas, evidentemente, este trabalho fica maior pelos seguintes motivos:

1. A designação de atributos não fica juntamente com a classe que representa a entidade. Ela pode ficar na inicialização do contexto do Entity Framework (evento [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx)) ou em uma classe em separado (que herda [`EntityMappingConfiguration<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696748(v=vs.113).aspx));
2. A declaração é mais verbosa e nem todos os modificadores possíveis estão na *Fluent API*, fazendo o programador ter que escrever código a mais para fazer um esforço equivalente, como, por exemplo, [no uso do atributo `Index` com *Fluent API*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892553/creating-unique-index-with-entity-framework-6-1-fluent-api).

> Devo utilizar o DataAnnotations?

Sim.

> Qual a melhor forma de validá-las?

Os atributos trabalham sozinhos. Você não precisa fazer nada.

Se quiser, você pode [escrever seus próprios atributos de validação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=validationattribute), [herdando `ValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ou ainda, [implementar `IValidatableObject` no *Model*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ivalidatableobject). Essa interface força o programador a implementar um método `Validate` com as regras de negócio envolvendo dados da própria entidade. Aqui não envolve exatamente o Entity Framework: está mais envolvido com as regras de negócio.

Desta forma, a validação é feita de forma nativa em duas etapas: uma no *framework* que você está trabalhando (como o ASP.NET MVC, por exemplo, ou o [ASP.NET Data Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567.aspx)) e outra a nível de banco de dados. O único trabalho que o programador tem é recolher as mensagens de exceção no momento de enviar as modificações do contexto. [Esta pergunta tem uma resposta sobre como isso pode ser feito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors/).

Comment: Implementei o IValidatableObject e realmente estava errado na resposta anterior... Segui o seu exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94776/como-utilizar-ivalidatableobject

Answer (score 2):

Se essa forma "clara" e "limpa" for uma maneira correta.

Se sua aplicação tem como fim a interface de usuário:

• Crie DTOs (View Models) e aplique os atributos Data Annotations nela.

Logo após isso, utilize o ***Assertion Concern Pattern*** para validar a integridade dos dados (se precisar de exemplo: https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples_NET/blob/master/iddd_common/Domain.Model/AssertionConcern.cs).

• E pra validar regra de negócio, você pode utilizar o ***Specification Pattern*** (https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications)

É uma forma segmentada e correta de validação.

**EDIÇÃO**: Vale salientar que o Assertion Concern Pattern e Specification Pattern devem estar e referenciar as entidades de domínio.