# Validação da cadastro repetido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma classe chamada `Matricula`. Ela recebe o cadastro de `Aluno` e de `Serie`.

Preciso fazer uma validação, onde caso o aluno já esteja matriculado em uma série cadastrada, a página apresenta uma mensagem informando que ele já está matriculado e não deixe que o mesmo seja matriculado novamente.

Abaixo está o código da matrícula:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace bj_cursosonline.Models
{
    public class Matricula
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [Display(Name = "Aluno")]
        public int ALUNOSID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [Display(Name = "Série")]
        public int SERIESID { get; set; }

        public virtual Series SERIES { get; set; }

        public virtual Alunos ALUNO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe de Aluno:

```
public enum SEXOALUNO
{
    MASCULINO, FEMININO
}

public class Alunos
{
    [Key]

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
    public string NOME { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sexo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
    public SEXOALUNO? SEXO { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Data em formato inválido!")]
    public DateTime DATANASCIMENTO { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Matricula>
        Matricula
    { get; set; }
}
```

Classe de Série:

```
public enum TURMA
{
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
}

public enum TURNO
{
    MANHÃ, TARDE, NOITE
}

public class Series
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição:")]
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Turma:")]
    public TURMA? TURMA { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Turno: ")]
    public TURNO? TURNO { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    [Display(Name = "Número da Sala:")]
    public int NUMSALA { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Avaliacoes>
        Avaliacoes
    { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Matricula>
        Matricula
    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Teria como colocar a classe SERIE e ALUNO também? Além disso você está utilizando o que para realizar suas consultas no Banco de Dados?

Comment: A melhor forma é pelo banco de dados. Via C# é muito mais código.

Comment: você poderia adicionar uma unique index na sua tabela, mas verifique sua regra de negócio, por exemplo: imagine que um aluno seja matriculado no ano de 2015, não completou a série, e agora em 2017 vai se matricular de novo. Teria que excluir a matricula anterior ? Perderia o histórico anterior dele ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso o ideal é antes de você salvar, você fazer uma verificação se já possui um cadastro desse no seu Banco, caso tenha ele retorne uma mensagem de erro.

Uma boa maneira de fazer essa validação é usando [IValidatableObject](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94782/26133), com ele você pode implementar suas próprias validações na sua classe.

```
namespace bj_cursosonline.Models
{
    public class Matricula : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [Display(Name = "Aluno")]
        public int ALUNOSID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [Display(Name = "Série")]
        public int SERIESID { get; set; }

        public virtual Series SERIES { get; set; }

        public virtual Alunos ALUNO { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // aqui você faz uma consulta no Banco de dados e busca se já existe um cadastro desse aluno na serie
            var result = db.Matriculas.Count(m => m.ALUNOSID == ALUNOSID && m.SERIESID == SERIESID); 
            if (result > 0)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Já existe uma Matricula para esse aluno nessa Serie", new string[] { "SERIESID" });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Segue mais exemplos de como utilizar o `IValidatableObject` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ivalidatableobject